# Apache Zeppelin tutorial failing

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Recently I installed Zeppelin from git using  `mvn clean package -Pspark-1.5 -Dspark.version=1.5.1 -Phadoop-2.4 -Pyarn -Ppyspark -DskipTests` and I can't run the tutorial because of this error:

```
java.net.ConnectException
```

Any idea why this is happening? I haven't modified any of the conf files because I am interested in running it using the embedded Spark binaries.

I already check most of the threads here and none of them has worked.

Thanks

EDIT: I am using a Mac

Comment: Please add more details, 1. Stack trace 2. What tutorial you've tried

Comment: it seems that you have lost your internet connection during the build. Have you retired it?

Comment: @user3276768 ApacheZeppelin generates server and interpreter logs under `./logs` dir. Could you update the post including the `.log` files?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Zeppelin](http://zeppelin.apache.org) uses [multi-process architecture](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/development/writingzeppelininterpreter.html), where ZeppelinServer process communicates with InterpreterGroup process though Apache Thrift API

[image: Apache Zeppelin architecture]

This error usually indicates that ZeppelinServer process can not reach Interpreter process, running on same machine due to abnormal executor termination of the latter.

More details can be found in Interpreter process logs `./logs/zeppelin-interpreter-<interpreter name>-<username>-<hostname>.log` and ZeppelinServer process logs under `./logs/zeppelin-<username>-<hostname>.log`