# Apache Zeppelin running on spark occurs java ConnectionException

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I want to ask some question about using appache-zeppelin installation.

1. I downloaded the zeppelin-0.5.5-incubating-bin-all
2. configure export JAVA_HOME=/sparkDemo/java-1.8.0-openjdk in zeppelin-env.sh and zeppelin.server.port 8084 in zeppelin-site.xml. I didn't configure SPARK_HOME in zeppelin-env.sh because i wanna use Zeppelin embedded Spark libraries.

But when i run the zeppelin tutorial code in my window browser,occur the following error: enter image description here

And even i configure SPARK_HOME, export MASTER in zeppelin-env.sh and create new interpreter in zeppelin web UI,the same error occurs.

Thanks a lot for responding me!
[Stack Trace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucs9U.jpg)

Comment: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) at

Comment: The error is like this When I tried to run zepplin demo.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioined in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947961/apache-zeppelin-tutorial-failing/41237370#41237370), most probably the issue is that Interpreter process quite due to some error.

More details on particular error could be found in:

- Interpreter process log

  `./logs/zeppelin-interpreter-<interpreter name>-<username>-<hostname>.log`
- and ZeppelinServer process log under

  `./logs/zeppelin-<username>-<hostname>.log`